# Given 2 values for $P(X \gt A)$, and that x follows the Gaussian PDF, find expected value and standard deviation

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals

Given that $P(X \gt 4) = 10^{-2}$ and that $P(X \gt 5) = 10^{-5}$ and that the random variable $X$ follows the Gaussian PDF, find the expected value and the standard deviation.

To solve the above, I thought of solving a $2\times2$ system of equations.
The equations would be derived from the two given data about the probability of $X$, by using this formula:
$$P(X \gt A) = \int_u^\infty {1\over \sqrt{2\times\pi}}\times e^{-{z^2 \over 2}}dz = Q(u)$$

Where $u = {A-m_X \over \sigma_X}$

I would use the two probabilities and by solving the $2\times2$ system I would have found $m$ and $\sigma$.

So after that, due to the Gaussian PDF, we have that $m_X = m$ and that $\sigma_X^2 = \sigma^2$.

But I am having hard time solving the 1st integral, after reaching here:

$$ {1 \over \sqrt{2 \times \pi}} \times \sqrt{e} \times \int_u^\infty e^{-z^2}dz = 10^{-2} $$

after which I got the integral above and tried to solve it by substitution of $k = z^2$ but at the end (after solving this integral) I got an extraneous $z$ at the result, which is wrong.

Comment: Are you not permitted to use the tables of the standard normal distribution? Or even calculate the inverse cdf by computer?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: Which tables do you mean? Also, why would I need to calculate the inverse cdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse cdf appears because

$$P(X \gt A) = \int_u^\infty {1\over \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-{z^2 \over 2}}dz = \Phi\left(-\frac {A-m_X}{\sigma_X}\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow -\frac {A-m_X}{\sigma_X} = \Phi^{-1}\left (P(X \gt A)\right)$$

So in your case

$$-\frac {4-m_X}{\sigma_X} = \Phi^{-1}\left (10^{-2}\right)$$

and

$$-\frac {5-m_X}{\sigma_X} = \Phi^{-1}\left (10^{-3}\right)$$

where $\Phi()$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: So it is safe to say that $P(X \gt A) = Q( {A-m_X \over \sigma_X})$, right? Where $Q$ is the complement function of CDF of the standard normal distribution. Because this is the function that we were presented in our lectures. So, what you've wrote becomes $P(X \gt A) = 10^{-2} \Rightarrow Q({4-m_x \over \sigma_X}) = 10^{-2} \Rightarrow {4-m_x \over \sigma_X} = Q^{-1}(10^{-2}) $. In which $ Q^{-1}(10^{-2}) = \Phi(10^{-2})$, right? But how can I find this value?

Comment: The gaussian integral does not have an analytical solution. That's why we use tables of its values, and that's why computers nowadays (e.g. spreadsheet programs) have ready made functions that calculate the standard normal cdf and its inverse

Comment: In your last step you are missing a minus - don't forget, $Q(x) = 1-\Phi(x) = \Phi(-x)$ the last equality by the properties of the standard normal cdf.

Comment: Thank you for the info, Aleco! To elaborate on my solution, I stopped up to the ${4-m_X\over\sigma_X} = Q^{-1}(10^(-2))$ and then looked up the table of the values of the Q function and then selected the most appropriate x that produces the $10^(-2)$ result.

Comment: That's it. Then the same for the $10^{-3}$ result, and you have your $2\times 2$ system of equations in two unknowns.